# angularjs wth webapi deployment in aws and CORS issue

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api, cors

Situation: I am building an ecommerce site using angular/.netwebapi. The key is - it needs to be deployed for multiple customers who share same set of webapi services (which behind the scene talks to mongoDB catalog and manages mysql order database). 
And I need to have seprate folders for each customers because of static and functional rule sets that changes across.

**Question 1:** How do I deploy angular app in virtual folders so that my urls can be http://mydomain.com/cust1, http://mydomain.com/cust2 etc. As I tried it breaks all path to js and static files

**Question 2:** I sort of solve the #1 by creating sites in multiple ports and host each store in different ports. That would work. But I really don't want my .Net Web Api app to be a central one. So I get CORS issue when I try to access a service running in http://mydomain.com/api/service from a page served from port <> 80 (like http://mydomain.com:8081/index.html#/mypage).

**Question 3:** I believe #1 and 2 can be solved if I use a subdomain approach. So each store is hosted to different subdomain (like cust1.mydomain.com, cust2.mydomain.com and each pointing to different folder) and webapi is hosted in one virtual directory (e.g. mydomain.com/api). I shall try it out in IIS shortly.

**Question 4:** However my real intent was to deploy the angular app in linux box and host services in windows. As we decided to put everything aws, I am not sure how can we have both linux and windows box within one domain so that I don't caught into CORS again. Any pointer to that would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All

Finally looks like things are resolved.
My config was --

1. Angular app hosted in nginx server (mydomain.com)
2. Web services are hosted in windows 2012 server (app.mydomain.com)

** they are both in aws in same region.

I had to do multiple things to make cors work:

1. change app.config in angular app.js by adding following lines (Thanks to http://better-inter.net/enabling-cors-in-angular-js/).

   app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
       $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
       delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
   }
2. This took care of GET requests. However for POST, angular fires OPTION requests first to check the web server acceptance (per W3C). So web server has to play accordingly. So I used a old but very effective CORSHandler class from my existing .Net MVC projects. Youc an read details here - http://dlr2008.wordpress.com/2013/06/17/rest-web-api-and-cors/
   There are numerous mention of this in various posts - but this one only (in my knowledge explains how it works)
3. With 1 and 2, things should have worked -but didn't. So it was time for "undocumented" things. Well seems like we need to disable webdav to let the OPTION request reach the corshandler that we defined in #2. Made changes in web.config per this post --> http://brockallen.com/2012/10/18/cors-iis-and-webdav/

Finally all worked together ...

I am quite sure many people pulled their hairs especially on #3 because I did. Hope this will save few hours of all such poor souls ... hth

Answer (score 0):

Reducing this problem down it sounds like enabling CORS will be your solution.

If you're using IIS / ASP.NET you can do this either in:

- IIS by adding an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header to a site or virtual directory
- ASP.NET with *Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")*;

Comment: For webAPI I am already doing that (2nd one). But ideally my HTML files (that runs angulrjs) will be hosted into linux/nginx cluster and webapi services will be accessed from client directly without going through any webserver.
So the browser will prevent CORS.
I have created a public DNS with both domains and doing my tests. Once successful will update the forum.
At the same time if someone else have some other pointers, please let me know.

Comment: You might want to consider hosting those files on S3 or Cloudfront. You can specify the CORS headers there as well. I'm not familiar with the way to do it on nginx but this might help http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html

Comment: I sort of did that using corshandler - but key was webdav - which I had no clue why I had to disable